# Why does by torch.optim.SGD method learning rate change?

Tags: pytorch, learning-rate

With SGD learning rate should not be changed during epochs but it is. Help me understand why it happens please and how to prevent this LR changing?

```
import torch
params = [torch.nn.Parameter(torch.randn(1, 1))]
optimizer = torch.optim.SGD(params, lr=0.9)
scheduler = torch.optim.lr_scheduler.StepLR(optimizer, 1, gamma=0.9)
for epoch in range(5):
    print(scheduler.get_lr())
    scheduler.step()
```

Output is:

```
[0.9]
[0.7290000000000001]
[0.6561000000000001]
[0.5904900000000002]
[0.5314410000000002]
```

My torch version is 1.4.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using the command  `torch.optim.lr_scheduler.StepLR(optimizer, 1, gamma=0.9)` (meaning actually `torch.optim.lr_scheduler.StepLR(optimizer, step_size=1, gamma=0.9)`) thus you are multiplying the learning rate by `gamma=0.9` every `step_size=1` step:

- 0.9     = 0.9
- 0.729   = 0.9*0.9*0.9
- 0.6561  = 0.9*0.9*0.9*0.9
- 0.59049 = 0.9*0.9*0.9*0.9*0.9

The only "strange" point is that it missing 0.81=0.9*0.9 at the second step (UPDATE: see [Szymon Maszke answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61600925/3871961) for an explanation)

To prevent early decreasing, if you have `N` samples in your dataset, and the batch size is D, then set `torch.optim.lr_scheduler.StepLR(optimizer, step_size=N/D, gamma=0.9)` to decrease at each epoch. To decrease each E epoch set `torch.optim.lr_scheduler.StepLR(optimizer, step_size=E*N/D, gamma=0.9)`

Comment: Great! Thank you for such precise description!

Comment: @Alex if the answer resolved your issue, kindly accept it - see [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: @xiawi See my answer about "stange" behavior or `optimizer` step without `0.81`.

Answer (score 1):

This is just what `torch.optim.lr_scheduler.StepLR` is supposed to do. It changes the learning rate. From the pytorch documentation:

> Decays the learning rate of each parameter group by gamma every step_size epochs. Notice that such decay can happen simultaneously with other changes to the learning rate from outside this scheduler. When last_epoch=-1, sets initial lr as lr

If you are trying to optimize `params`, your code should look more like this (just a toy example, the precise form of `loss` will depend on your application)

```
for epoch in range(5):
  optimizer.zero_grad()
  loss = (params[0]**2).sum()
  loss.backward()
  optimizer.step()
```

Comment: Thank you @joemrt for your answer!

Answer (score 1):

To expand upon [xiawi's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61599725/10886420) answer about "strange" behavior (`0.81` is missing): It is PyTorch's default way since `1.1.0` release, check [documentation](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/optim.html#how-to-adjust-learning-rate), namely this part:

> [...] If you use the learning rate scheduler (calling
>   `scheduler.step()`) before the optimizer’s update (calling
>   `optimizer.step()`), this will skip the first value of the learning rate
>   schedule.

Additionally you should get a `UserWarning` thrown by this function after the first `get_lr()` call as you do not call `optimizer.step()` at all.